# Java email received from standalone class, but not when executed within a servlet

Tags: java, email, servlets

Using Java, I can send email from a toy standalone class (with hard-coded data) perfectly fine, and I receive the email within seconds.

When the *exact same code* is called in the context of a servlet, however, the code executes without failure, *but* I don't actually receive the email.

How could that be? Is there something special about the servlet environment?
I'm running Tomcat 6, JRE 1.5.

Here is the code (I have edited my data):

```
public void sendEmail(String aSubject, String aBody){
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.host", "smtp.blah.ca");
props.put("mail.from", "from-blah@blah.ca");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null /*no authenticator*/);
System.out.println("JRE" + System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println(session.getProperties());
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
try {
  message.addRecipient(
    Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("to-blah@blah.com")
  );
  message.setSubject(aSubject);
  message.setText(aBody);
  Transport.send(message);
}
catch (MessagingException ex){
  System.err.println("Cannot send email. " + ex);
}
```

}

Edit: the email is recieved when the content (email body) is small. When the content is large, it's not recieved.

Comment: Hm, is it a local (your PC) Tomcat instance or a remote one (hosted)? Did you check the logs (your exception handling is bit clumsy)? Are SMTP servers the same, any security rules (relaying, forwarding)?

Comment: Local instance (my PC). Nothing in logs. Same SMTP server (all props data exactly the same). Jar shows version 1.4 of the mail spec in both cases.

Comment: Is the method really executed? Can you confirm you see the `System.out` messages?

Comment: It's related to the content of the email somehow. When I truncate it to 3 short words, it's fine. The content of the 'real' email is longer, and is described here: http://www.web4j.com/web4j/javadoc/hirondelle/web4j/webmaster/TroubleTicket.html

Comment: The debug logging shows that the email is sent without error. Maybe this is just a slowing of email transfer, because of size? It's not very large, though..

Answer (score 0):

This is not java-related at all.

I tested a large email with a normal email client. The same behavior was seen: the email is sent fine, but I'm not receiving it in a timely manner, for some reason. (I haven't seen this kind of behavior before, but there it is...)